# Entity Framework migration could not create foreign key constraint

Tags: entity-framework, foreign-keys, many-to-many, constraints, database-migration

I had 2 tables:

```
public class Work
{
    public int WorkId { get; set; }
    (...)
}

public class Check
{
    public int CheckId { get; set; }
    (...)
}
```

Then I wanted to add a many to many relationship with payload between them so:

```
public class WorkCheck
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    [ForeignKey("Work")]
    public int WorkId { get; set; }
    public virtual Work Work { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    [ForeignKey("Check")]
    public int CheckId { get; set; }
    public virtual Check Check { get; set; }

    (...)
}

   public class Work
    {
        public int WorkId { get; set; }
        (...)
        public virtual IList<WorkCheck> WorkChecks { get; set; }
    }

    public class Check
    {
        public int CheckId { get; set; }
        (...)
        public virtual IList<WorkCheck> WorkChecks { get; set; }
    }
```

In the package manager console I ran the command "Add-Migration WorkCheckTableAdded" and no errors were shown.

But right after, when I executed the "Update-Database -verbose" command, I got the exception:
**"Foreign key 'FK_dbo.WorkCheck_dbo.Work_WorkId' references invalid column 'WorkId' in referenced table 'dbo.Work'.
Could not create constraint. See previous errors."**

Comment: Does the `WorkId` column already exist under that name in the `Work` table and is it a primary key before you run the migration? Or is the column name different (remapped with `HasColumnName`)? And is the database SQL Server?

Comment: The WorkId column already exists and it's primary. Tomorrow I'll create a new blank project and test this issue again.

Comment: If I start a project from scratch the issue does not occur. Do you know how can I reset my old project's migrations so that my initial migration contains my current schema (without workcheck table)?

Answer (score 1):

This problem does not occur in a new project. It may had to do with some failed migration script in my project. In order to reset the migrations I deleted the Migrations folder in the VS project and the target database.